# Text classification - is it overfitting? How can I prove?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, text-classification, multilabel-classification

I have a multi classification problem and my data involves sequence of letters. It is a labelled data (used label encoder to encode string labels to numeric). There could be partial strings for the same class. May strings match but some could be just slightly different.

I am preparing my data with k-mer and countvectoriser (fitted on train data and transformed train and test data). With the combination of kmer size and ngram sizes, the dimension (feature size) varies between 8000+ to 35000+. I do not think that there is test information leak at the training of the model.

I fit different algorithms on the train data and test to review the generalisation. The test scores (accuracy, f1-score, precision and recall) are coming pretty high (more than 99%). Even though this is testing, do you think the model could be overfitting due to high dimensionality (curse of dimensionality)? I understand that if training score is high and generalises poorly then its overfitting but here the test scores are very high. This is not models as different algorithms giving similar results, its certainly about the data.

If I apply PCA to get 10 components which covers 99% variance, the test score on testing is high too. If I use selectkfeatures to select just about 10 best features, then the scores come down.

How can I prove that this is not overfitting? Should I always go for reduced features size (through selection or pca) with such high dimension size?

Comment: Please note, the data for all the classes is quite balanced and I do 70 - 30 split for train and test.

Comment: To whom do you want to "prove" this? Also, is the data set much larger than the number of features (for instance  > x100 times) ?

Comment: Hi Pac0, the score for me was for me a case of overfitting and wanted to get the opinion on it really. total data samples are about 80k but feature sizes vary between 8k to 35k as per kmer ngram configuration.

Answer (score 3):

If your test score is high, then below are the possibilities

1. Overlap in test and train data: This can happen if you have duplicate records and while splitting one fall into train and other into test
2. Data Leak: If the class label information is some how encoded in the features. This can be easily verified: if train score are almost 100% even with basic models. Check this resource for understand what is a [data leak](https://www.kaggle.com/alexisbcook/data-leakage).
3. You really have succeeded in building a good model

I suggest check the above 2 possibilities first and then try out K-fold cross validation.

Comment: Hi Muhhiga, 1) There is no overlap but many of the test records for all classes do match exactly to what exists in the training data. Are you sayig this condition can be called as overlap? 2) Train and test both are near 100%, not sure how it would got encoded in a feature (labels and data are totally separate), and how this feature can be found as the feature size is too huge. May be the the top frequencies of top 10 biggest features?

Comment: You cannot have same record in both test and train, then there is no point in having test set. Test data should be hidden for training so if you saying exactly matching records are both in test and training the it is wrong (point 1).

Comment: 3) The models from different algorithms are not anything special, I do believe it is the data that materialises to these scores. but do not think there is any leak. The kfold stratified splits and cross validation scores are more than 99% too on the train and test data, Not all the test samples match to training samples but many are similar. do you think I should remove them?

Comment: This answer is very helpful. This "model too great" is an easy trap to fall into (bad "testing" data that give a misplaced confidence into the model), and you explained clearly what could be happening. Thanks.